# Of the multiple cnf files in /etc/mysql/conf.d/ dir, which would be the last one to be read (and will eventually take precedence)?

Tags: mysql, percona, my.cnf

For some reasons (and only for some days to come) we are going to have 2 cnf files in `/etc/mysql/conf.d` directory, apart from the default one `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Now I know this can be disastrous, and we are working to resolve this.

But for the sake of knowledge ....

The config of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` will be over-ridden by the cnf file in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/`

But between the 2 cnf files in `/etc/mysql/conf.d`, lets say `a.cnf` and `b.cnf`, which one would take precedence and why?

MySql version is "Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.30, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, there can be only one config file. But mine ends with

```
#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

and so it is directly responsible for "merging" those additional ones into itself.

The `!includedir` directive is covered in the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html which states:

> There is no guarantee about the order in which the option files in the directory will be read.

So it probably depends on the OS and filesystem but you should not depend on it anyway, even when it seems "stable" for now.

I sugget using the `!include` directive instead and maybe a different folder for those config files where the order matters.